# Can I use word 'gathering' for virtual presence

Tags: american-english

I was on a group chat with my team, there I have said "Thanks for gathering real quick".

I some how feel that this is incorrect, as I am thinking that gathering is generally used when you are physically present.

Comment: "thanks for gathering so quickly."

Comment: I think I was not clear. My question is, Is "gather" a right word to use if we are in virtual mode, like nowadays we are having chatting on internet or connecting  video calls, I mean meeting not in person. If we are asking people to join video call or in group chat, can we say thanks for gathering?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  jamesnotjim gave you the answer to gathering, but told you that you should not say "real quick", but didn't tell you what you should say instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A gathering can be real or metaphorical. But "real quick" is a separate issue.

Whether it works or not depends upon how comfortable you are with metaphorical expressions. But I don't think using this term in this context would raise any eyebrows. "Gathering" is a synonym for "meeting" and, these days, no one would think it strange to have an online or virtual meeting. Most meetings I attend these days have a call-in or webinar number for those who can't be physically present. People travel. Workforces are geographically distributed. This is common, now.

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
A good answer is comprehensive and contains an explanation of ***why*** it is correct.
Links to external resources are encouraged.
For help writing a good answer, see [answer].

Comment: Fixed. Lengthened.

Comment: Certainly. I should have done so initially.